# Positioning images in a div box in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to put five images in a 200px200px box. In four corners, four images, and center one image. How I can do it with HTML and CSS?

I have tried this, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    .box{
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;

    }

    body{
        text-align: center;


    }

    .img1{
        float: left;
    }

    .img3{
        float: right;
    }

    .img4{
        float: right;
    }

    .img5{
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
    <img src="frog.jpg" class="img1">

    <img src="frog.jpg" class="img2">

    <img src="frog.jpg" class="img3">

    <img src="frog.jpg" class="img4">

    <img src="frog.jpg" class="img5">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we see your efforts?

Comment: Please edit your question. I can't read this

Comment: Please try this link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/how-to-create-border-images-using-css3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning for the images in the corner, and I use the `line-height` trick to vertically center the middle image.

```css
.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.topleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bottomleft {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}


.bottomright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.center {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="topleft">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="topright">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="bottomleft">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="bottomright">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="center">
</div>
```

Comment: How can i put it in the center of page? can u help?